# How can I a custom instance of the default Application instance?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to create my own Application object, similar to the following:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Android
{
    public class MyApplication : Application
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            // do application specific things here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the app to use the `MyApplication` object? My understanding is that I have to specify this in the manifest, but I can't get that to work. The application deploys fine, but it fails to run after.

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
          package="abc.mypackage">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
    <application android:label="MyMobileApp" 
               android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen" 
               android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
               android:icon="@drawable/Logo" 
               android:name=".MyNameSpace.Android.MyApplication"/>
</manifest>
```

Note that I've tried all variations of upper and lowercase letters in the `android:name=".MyNameSpace.Android.MyApplication"` attribute, including with and without the leading `.` character.

If I remove that line, the application runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add the following class Attribute & Constructor to my custom Application class:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Android
{
    [Application(Debuggable = true, ManageSpaceActivity = typeof(MyMainActivity))]
    public class MyApplication : Application
    {

        public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            // do application specific things here
        }

    }
}
```